# Program hogging all my resources and not completing (possible infinite loop?)

Tags: java, eclipse, sorting, lag

I wrote this program to take in records of Students from a file and put them into an array.  I then bubble sort them and try to print them.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentTest 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String name;
    String address;
    String major;
    double gpa;
    int classLevel;
    int college;
    String idNumber;

    Scanner fileIn = null;
    try
    {
        fileIn = new Scanner (new FileInputStream("student.dat"));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File not found");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    Student[] aStudent = new Student[15];
    int index = 0;

    for (index=0; index < 15;)
    {
        while (fileIn.hasNext())
        {
        name = fileIn.nextLine();
        address = fileIn.nextLine();
        major = fileIn.nextLine();
        gpa = fileIn.nextDouble();
        classLevel = fileIn.nextInt();
        college = fileIn.nextInt();
        fileIn.nextLine();
        idNumber = fileIn.nextLine();
        aStudent[index] = new Student(name, address, major, gpa, classLevel, college, idNumber);
        aStudent[index].Display();
        System.out.println(index);
        index++;
        }
    }


    Student temp= null;
    for (int pass = 0; pass < (index-1); pass++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < (index - 1); c++)
        {
            if  (aStudent[c].getName().compareTo(aStudent[c+1].getName()) > 0)
            {
                temp = aStudent[c];
                aStudent[c]=aStudent[+1];
                aStudent[+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int d = 0; d < aStudent.length; d++)
    {
        aStudent[d].Display();
        System.out.println();
    //aStudent[d].Display();
    }
    //System.out.println(aStudent);
}
}
```

the console will display the first print of the unsorted list from when it is loading the array, and then just sit there.  I let it go for ten minutes and it still displayed the red "terminate" icon in in eclipse (indicating that it was still running).  It was also eating half of my resources the whole time.  How can I resolve this?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you looping to

```
while (fileIn.hasNext() && index < 15)
```

No for loop needed

Think - what would happen if index was less than 15 and there was no next record

Comment: I changed it, but now I am getting a null pointer exception (and it's obvious that my sort isn't working . . . )

Comment: I changed it, but now I am getting a null pointer exception on "if  (aStudent[c].getName().compareTo(aStudent[c+1].getName())>0)"

Comment: What IDE are you using.  You should really learn to use a debugger.  Put a breakpoint at this line and see what the value of 'c' is, or whether the student record is correctly populated.  By the way, could you please mark my answer as correct.

Comment: Eclipse Standard Kepler.  I messed around with debug and realized that I had accidentally commented out the instantiation of my students in the array.  However, i also discovered that my sort is not working.  For some reason, my c starts at 0, moves to one on the second pass through it's if loop, and then never changes again.

Comment: it's great that I discovered it, but I have no idea why it is happening . . .

Comment: well as you are looping through the same array that you are modifying, things are bound to get messy.  Maybe use a new 'sortedresults' array where you can insert and/or move the objects.

Answer (score 0):

`index++` is inside the `while` loop that is nested within the `for` loop.  Your `for` loop can only exit if the `while` loop iterates at least 15 times.